# How to Create Custom Gridview in Android?

Tags: android, gridview

I want to create Custom GridView like this attached below image.
Grid item not in line.
So how i can do this?

[image]

Give me some idea.

Thanks,
Girish

Comment: try with this link https://github.com/vladexologija/PinterestListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/

May be above link will give you best possible solution. Its pintrest kind of adapterview.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try to create 2 `ListView` and forward touch event from one list to another and backward to scroll them simlteniously. So one listview for left column and one for right.  I suppose this is the easyest way to create something like that.

Comment: @Evos...can u explain me in brief or example??

Comment: @Patel i don't know about any example of such solutions, brief: you must programmatically copy touches from one list view (it's scroll) to other. This could create visual effect of single listview, but i've neved done such things before, so i can't give you any code example.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following links. They are open source libraries.

1. https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView
2. https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary

Might this can help you out.